# randomly split up substrings

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split up substring charaters from a string from what i have tryed so far has failed even looping within a loop.

An example result from string "1234567890" the output could look like as follows

```
12
345
6
7890
```

.

```
var randomChar = ""
var str = "123456789";

for (var j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
randomChar = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

console.log(str.substr(j, randomChar));
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific in how random the separation can be? Is it even random in how many different substrings there are? Or is it just random in the size of the substrings?

Comment: @aug The seperation for each split could be up to 4 charaters, and the total substring splits being would best be determained by the remaining charaters, i hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go:

```
    var substrSize;
    while (str.length) {
         substrSize = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1; // at most 4? 
         if (substrSize >= str.length)
             randomChar = str;
         else
             randomChar = str.substr(0,substrSize);
         str = str.substr(randomChar.length);
         console.log(randomChar);
    }
```

or alternatively:

```
    var j = 0;
    while (j < str.length) {
         var n= j+Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
         if (n> str.length) n= str.length;
         console.log(str.substring(j, n));
         j = n;
    }
```

or alternatively:

```
    var j = 0;
    while (j < str.length) {
         var n= Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
         if (j+n> str.length) n= str.length-j;
         console.log(str.substr(j, n));
         j += n;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you always iterate `str.length` times. After cutting out for example first 3 random characters you should start from 4th, not from 2nd.

And here is an elegant recursive solution, much different from yours:

```
function randString(s) {
   if(s.length > 0) {
     var pivot = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3);
     console.info(s.substring(0, pivot));
     randString(s.substring(pivot));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var randomChar = ""
var str = "123456789";
var j = 0;
while (j < str.length) {
    randomChar = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
    console.log(str.substr(j, randomChar));
    j += randomChar;
}
```